# Mongoose Events doesn't fire on connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to console.log when mongoose connection is done. it is successfully getting connected but it never fires 'connected' event. This is my mongoose implementation.

```
const config = require("../../config");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connect = async () => {
  const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.databaseURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  connection.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });
  return connection.connection;
};

const disconnect = async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
};

module.exports = {
  connect,
  disconnect,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection socket event will call using `mongoose`, and before this remove `await` from `const connection = await mongoose.connect(`,

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

Refer mongoose [connection-events](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events).

Comment: well in my case the event is not firing..i cant figure out why

Comment: just remove await from connect method, i have updated an answer.

Comment: shouldn't i wait for mongoose to connect first before returning it?

Comment: no that is why that have provided socket event option, if you want to wait for connection then event will not work.

Comment: If i write event listeners before the connection it will work.

Comment: yes it will work and when its connected it will listen.